# How to activate JMX on remote Glassfish server for access with jconsole?

Tags: java, glassfish, jmx, jconsole

I would like to monitor remote glassfish server. I have enabled JMX Connection in domain.xml:

```
<jmx-connector accept-all="true" address="0.0.0.0" auth-realm-name="admin-realm" enabled="true" name="system" port="8686" protocol="rmi_jrmp" security-enabled="false">
```

But this didn't help. I still can't connect to server with JConsole. Then I've found solution - I need to specify JVM properties in domain.xml to open 8686 port for remote connection. 
So I added this lines into **java-config** section:

```
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false</jvm-options>
```

But now when I'm starting server, I'm getting following errors:

> Could not load Logmanager
>   "com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager"
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ServerLogManager
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>           at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:166)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.util.logging.LogManager.(LogManager.java:156)
>           at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:273)
>           at sun.management.snmp.util.MibLogger.(MibLogger.java:57)
>           at sun.management.snmp.util.MibLogger.(MibLogger.java:42)
>           at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.(ConnectorBootstrap.java:760)
>           at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:127)
>           at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:239)
>   javax.management.JMRuntimeException:
>   Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder
>   class
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder
>           at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:480)
>           at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.getNewMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:511)
>           at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.newMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:298)
>           at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:213)
>           at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer(MBeanServerFactory.java:174)
>           at sun.management.ManagementFactory.createPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:302)
>           at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:504)
>           at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.initialize(ConnectorBootstrap.java:392)
>           at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:127)
>           at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:239)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>           at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.loadBuilderClass(MBeanServerFactory.java:423)
>           at javax.management.MBeanServerFactory.checkMBeanServerBuilder(MBeanServerFactory.java:465)
>           ... 9 more Exception thrown by the agent :
>   javax.management.JMRuntimeException:
>   Failed to load MBeanServerBuilder
>   class
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.jmx.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder

How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to solve the problem are:
1. use default settings
2. add -Djava.rmi.server.hostname= in the JVM Options of the instance of GlassFish.

Comment: Just to be sure: The first step - did that involve removing all the com.sun.management.jmxremote settings from JVM options?

Comment: It means to keep them the same as they were out-of-the-box. If the JMX settings exists - let them be, if they doesn't - don't add them.

Answer (score 5):

Still mystical behavior, but with these 4 settings you can connect to the JVM running Glassfish (add to domain.xml in admin console, restart required)

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=yourhost
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8686
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

**Beware** ! This is not safe, as anyone now can connect a jconsole to it !

IMO this is not the Glassfish way, which is using the JMX connector.

(Above works in GF 3.1)

Comment: Thanks so much.  This is exactly the answer I've been looking for to remotely connect to a glassfish server running on a VM on my machine!

Comment: I add some extra setting: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false

Answer (score 3):

I ended up setting the following option to ensure that JMX with Glassfish is firewall friendly:

```
<jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.aas.jconsole.server.cbport=XXXX</jvm-options>
```

Where XXXX is the port number that you use in the firewall together with the application server configured JMX port number (usually 8686).

Read more in [this blogpost](http://blogs.oracle.com/tronds/entry/glassfish_and_jmx_through_a). Note that this feature requires a newer version of Glassfish. I've successfully used it with Glassfish 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it [GlassFish issue 1409](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1409)?

Comment: No. It's not. Also I'm using GF v2.1 (9.1.1) (build b60e-fcs)

Answer (score 0):

If run your application inside Glassfish app server, simply run the following asadmin command, you would need to restart all running servers for the change to take affect.

./asadmin enable-secure-admin

There are extra Glassfish server configurations to further enable security, see more at [Connecting remotely to Glassfish through JMX](https://blogs.oracle.com/prsad/entry/connecting_securely_to_glassfish_via).

You do need to follow the steps on JVM options, these are instructions for Java applications in general. For a Java application that runs with Glassfish application server, simply using the asadm command. That saved me lots of time!

** Another note, with only the settings using JVM options, Glassfish would fail to start with the above runtime exceptions.
** I am using GF3.1.2 and above, and Java 7.